# Text formatter using only strings

Tags: java, string

For our java class, we have to format text using `L allign`, `Centered`, and `R allign.`

I have figured out how to save the string into a row, but i am not sure how to reset the row.

Any help would be great!

```
public static String word(String text, int width) {

    String word = "";
    String all = "";
    String row = "";
    String newRow = "";
    int textlen = text.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char current = text.charAt(i);
        // works gives a word
        do {
            if (text.charAt(i) != ' ') {

                word += text.charAt(i);
            }
            i++;

        } while (text.charAt(i) != ' ' && i < textlen);
        // till here
        word += " ";
        // System.out.println("this is word: " +word);

        while (row.length() < width) {
            if (word.length() < width
                    && (row.length() + word.length()) < width) {
                row += word;
                if ((width - (row.length() + word.length())) < 3) {
                    System.out.println("here is row: " + row);
                }

            }
            if (word.length() > width
                    && (row.length() + word.length()) > width) {

            }
            word = "";
        }
        row = "";
    }

    return word;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you've got a loop starting `while(row.length()<width){`.  At this point of the code, you've got a single word.  What is there to loop?

Comment: What is your specific problem? How do your actual results differ from your expected results and what have you done so far to try and solve the problem?

Comment: @DavidWallace `row += word` modifies `row` inside the loop. The loop terminates once its size exceeds `width`.

Comment: @JasonC as of now my second <code>while(row.length()<width){ </code> is supoosed to reset my row, but it is not doing that

Comment: I want my row to print out, and then reset, and then print the new row out onto a new line

Comment: @user2994458 We don't know what "resetting a row" means. Please state your problem more precisely and *show how your actual results differ from your expected results*. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some question guidelines to help you get better answers.

Comment: String text is the user inputted text.  String word: will add new characters, until a space is detected(from text). String row, will save all of String word, until row >= width(user specified width). It is doing this as of now, but I want the String Row to clear out once the width is hit, and take in the next String words and output them into a new line. I want this to keep going, until all of text has been processed.

Comment: @JasonC - The loop doesn't do what you said it does.  Because `word` goes back to `""` as soon as it's been added to `row` once.  So this loop will either never run at all, or never terminate.  That's why I asked OP why he/she thought there should be a loop there.  My question wasn't so that someone other than OP would tell me (incorrectly) what the loop actually does.

Comment: @DavidWallace Ah I see it now.

Comment: how should I restate the loop, so it saves each new row?

Comment: OP - You've got most of the right bits in your program, but you're lacking some coherence about how to fit it all together.  My serious suggestion here would be to move away from your computer for half an hour, forget about all of the code you've written so far, and sketch out with pencil and paper how you think this should work.  Then try again with a blank slate.  Come back here and ask again if you have specific questions.  But right now, none of us can really help you when you yourself don't understand what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset a `String` variable back to an empty string, simply assign it to an empty string:

```
row = "";
```

Comment: but how do i add this, so that it fits into the loop?

Comment: You would put it at whatever point in your logic you want `row` to become an empty string... what do you *want* to happen?

Comment: well I am just confused as to how to make this loop take in new values of word, so that they can be outputted into new lines.                         `if (word.length() < width
                    && (row.length() + word.length()) < width) {
                row += word;
                if ((width - (row.length() + word.length())) < 3) {
                    System.out.println("here is row: " + row);
                }

            }
            if (word.length() > width
                    && (row.length() + word.length()) > width) {

            }`

Comment: As I said, you need to show your expected results and your actual results, otherwise you will not get an answer here and this question will ultimately closed due to quality issues. We don't know what you're talking about, what you're actually trying to do, or what "rows" or parsing words has to do with aligning text.

Comment: Variable string text records user inputted string(can be many words long). Variable word, scans text into word until a " "(space) is seen. Variable row records ("word") until row and word = width(user inputed variable). How do I use a loop to make row clear itself, and take in the next line of word?